# Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1738/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from April 1st 2015 through June 30th 2015.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2015-04..2015-06) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2015-04..2015-06). Since we currently get ~850/1400 questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 2nd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/330768)
- [Questions with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/330769)
- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/330770)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

If you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1848/49)**.

Answer (score 3):

So I've skimmed over the last quarter of questions and answers to look for the posts I'd deem good and diverse examples, be it by personal interest, quality, informativity or just originality. In contrast to just listing some exemplary questions and answers, I tried to group them a bit into some larger trends I observed this quarter. This is still not an exhaustive list, as there have been many good questions and answers. And of course this is entirely my own opinion.

---

In general I have to say that this quarter was for me largely characterized by many interesting questions and answers about the **background of characters, their actions, motivations and depictions**, from *Mad Max* and *Nightcrawler*, over *Avatar*, *The Lord of the Rings* and *Game of Thrones*, to Marvel's and DC's latest superhero fare. Some examples for this would be:

- [Is Captain America worthy of Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33875/49)

  [Is Captain America captain of the Avengers team?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33942/49)

  [What makes Ultron the person he is?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33751/49)

  [Why did Ultron want a flesh body?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35394/49)

  [What is the reason for Hulk's decision at the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33690/49)

  [Why didn't he get the power of Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33689/49)

  [Why did Hawkeye become immune to mind control effects?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34101/49)

  *Avengers: Age of Ultron* was a great source for interesting character-driven questions and answers. Especially the last question is also a very good example for a question that generated answers concentrating on entirely different but equally valid and interesting approaches to the problem, showing [what multiple answers are actually good for](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/762/49).
- [Why does Tyrion want to advise Daenerys?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35070/49)

  [Was Theon always loyal to Sansa?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35407/49)

  This quarter also saw the finale of *Game of Thrones*' 5th season and thus generated some interesting questions and answers about its characters.
- [How does Murphy overcome the “Red Asset”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34341/49)

  [Why does Grace become a different character when using her avatar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34578/49)

  Two really good answers to interesting questions that voiced some doubts about the given character portrayals. The answers really cut to the core of the respective movies' themes and their characters' depictions.
- [What was Saruman's motivation in the Lord of the Rings trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35514/49)

  This quarter also saw the death of actor Christopher Lee and this good question asking for the motivation of one his most recently portrayed characters was a good way to honor his legacy.
- [Is there any explanation for Lou Bloom's mannerisms and personality in Nightcrawler?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32935/49)

  Speaking about interesting character portrayals, a recent highlight was definitely *Nightcrawler*'s Lou Bloom, amazingly embodied by Jake Gyllenhaal. And this question gave a great opportunity to delve into this character and his background, for which Wolfgang Schmitt's interesting analysis provided a good approach.

---

On another note, we had some very good cases of **new answers that snitched acceptance from already existing inferior answers**. And this is usually a good thing, since it is always great when a new answer is superior enough to the existing ones to convince the asker to reconsider his acceptance, especially since new answers might often get forgotten and people might be repelled from answering accepted questions, thinking that they are already solved as best as possible. But afterall [Having multiple answers can be a great thing!](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/762/49) Examples for this would be:

- [Do I need to watch all James Bond movies starring Daniel Craig before watching Skyfall to understand the plot and characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34845/49)

  I can hardly resist an interesting James Bond question anyway and this answer is just great and covers many important aspects of the overall question, which the existing ones didn't to that degree.
- [Why sudden change in war boy's motives?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34673/49)

  I was a bit unsatisfied with the first answer to this but also not confident enough to provide my own. So I was very glad when this great and to the point answer came around and even more so when the acceptance was changed to it (disregarding if certain people think it doesn't have enough "citations").
- [Why did the Joker take the risk of placing a gun in Harvey Dent's hand?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33523/49)

  Basically every answer to this question is good and really cuts to the point of the problem, except for the top-voted one. This question was an absolute victim of the Hot Network Questions and one answer was upvoted into heaven albeit entirely missing the point of the question and concetrating on some absolutely irrelevant visual inconsistency. When the asker finally accepted one of the other answers he set a sign that reason can ultimately prevail over people voting carelessly.

---

We also had some interesting **questions that were rather controversial and on the verge of getting closed** for various reasons (some of them more valid and some less):

- [How does Iron Man's costume serve to emphasize the aspects of his character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33794/49)

  Another addition to the great character dirven questions of this quarter. While I agree that the question might be a bit too short and maybe a bit broad and the answers stay largely superficial, it is nevertheless an interesting and valid question to me. Most of the controversy around it sprang from the fact that it is a supposed "homework question". But this doesn't really matter as long as the question is valid. It is not our responsibility to question the asker's motives and if you have a problem with people taking "profit" from your answers, you're on the wrong site.
- [Why does 'The Wolf of Wall Street' contain so many nude scenes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34879/49)

  Another question where the asker's motives provided reason for controversy. Granted, the question wasn't phrased particularly well and objective at first. But after stripping it from the asker's personal moral judgments, it IMHO became an interesting question about the movie's portrayal of sex and nudity, as also seen in its answers, even if those might not be as exhaustive as they could be.
- [How do movie makers get people to watch a movie many times?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35362/49)

  This is quite a bit of a "list question" and might be a bit too broad to answer conclusively, but I think it might work, as can also seen by previous questions along those lines. It still has to be seen how it pans out, but [opening a bit more towards *some* kinds of supposed list questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1060/49) might not be that bad an idea.
- [Does the Film Drive Have a Cameo from the star of Maniac Cop](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35758/49)

  Not exactly that controversial and near to closing, but [identify-this-actor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-actor) is always a bit of a hot topic, often either giving too few information to know it's a movie at all or on the other hand being just irrelevant trivia easily looked up. Yet this question provided an interesting premise for motivating the question which elevates it beyond the usual [identify-this-actor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-actor) stuff.

---

Personally, this quarter was for me also characterized by a **raised interest into *Batman***, for whatever reason. Thus I revisited all his modern movie/TV incarnations, from Burton's and Timm/Radomski's, to Schumacher's and Nolan's, finally delved into some seminal works in Batman comic lore (never having read a comic apart from *Watchmen*), and also read some secondary material. I was thus very enthusiastic in composing some new answers to rather old questions:

- [Does Christopher Nolan's Batman have an overarching theme?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34185/49)
- [Is Batman Begins based on any Batman comic or was it entirely written from scratch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34999/49)

---

As every quarter, this time we also had some interesting **general questions about making, producing and selling movie and TV content**, from technical questions about the physical medium itself, over interesting film techniques in famous works, to box-office and distribution.

- [What is the Resolution of 35mm film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35801/49)
- [Was film actually “better” than digital media?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34452/49)
- [Why do some movies start with a big rotating circle and countdown?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33860/49)
- [How did they film Danny tricycle riding through the hotel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35043/49)
- [How much do 3D ticket prices affect gross revenue?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35980/49)
- [How are TV shows resurrected?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35771/49)

---

And last but not least, we also had many **answers that mostly convinced by finding good and authoritative references** to provide a conclusive answer (sometimes even to questions where you might not have expected much of an authoritatively sourced answer). Some examples would be (even if that list is by far not exhaustive):

- [What was going on with Dennis in 'Charlie Work' (S10E04)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36009/49)
- [Does Al Pacino really slap Diane Keaton in The Godfather II?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35029/49)
- [Did Keller get found in the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33409/49)
- [Should one watch the first three Mad Max movies before watching Fury Road?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34393/49)