# Rewards for the best answer from the 2nd quarter of 2015 [Completed]

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-event

We are starting a quarterly bounty reward event by taking inspiration from the [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1847/49). I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from April 1st 2015 through June 30th 2015 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/330765/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015-04-01&Count=962)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

**Results**:-

[Top answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/how-did-they-film-danny-tricycle-riding-through-the-hotel/35045#35045) has been given bounty worth 200 points.
As a consolation, [second highest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/is-it-really-as-easy-to-knock-someone-out-in-real-life-as-in-the-movies/35563#35563) scoring answer has been given 100 point bounty and 3rd place with a tie ([1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35794/why-didnt-aragorn-let-theoden-kill-grima/35796#35796),[2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35567/how-far-does-marlin-travel-to-find-nemo/35572#35572)) got 50 bounty each. Keep answering and thanks for making it successful and expecting more participation next time onward.

Comment: I loved this answer and think it deserves more love: [eWhy was the Hulkbuster program called Veronica?][1]


  [1]: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33734/why-was-the-hulkbuster-program-called-veronica/33736#33736

Comment: it just auto-converted my answer to a comment...

Comment: @DForck42 really, quite weird. Can you try again with bit more words maybe.

Comment: @DForck42 Are you sure such a feature even exists and you didn't just pick the wrong textbox? There isn't even a deleted answer from you on this question. I've never heard of such a feature and afterall we even had shorter answers in the past, too.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it might be something new, but i am 100% certain that i was in the right text box.  i used the link tool to put the link in...

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is *not* considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll.

Comment: @DForck42 I think i found [your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment), it happened with one more user but [rewording worked fro her](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/2342/1190).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catija's answer to the question

[how-did-they-film-danny-tricycle-riding-through-the-hotel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/how-did-they-film-danny-tricycle-riding-through-the-hotel/35045#35045)

It was one of my favorite movie scenes ever I always wondered how they managed to generate that eerie atmosphere from a kid riding a tricycle. The answer explained everything about that scene very thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Dannie's answer to the below mentioned question:-

[Is it really as easy to knock someone out in real life as in the movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/is-it-really-as-easy-to-knock-someone-out-in-real-life-as-in-the-movies/35563#35563)

**Reason:** I am personally fan of this kind of generic questions and whats better then a detailed answer to them. Even before it got accepted, I liked it more then any other.

Answer (score 2):

SystemDown's answer to the below mentioned question:

[How far does Marlin travel to find Nemo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35567/how-far-does-marlin-travel-to-find-nemo/35572#35572)

**Reason:** Not because of pretty pictures but for being a good elaborated answer and those image were just icing on cake.

Answer (score 2):

Avner Shahar- Kashtan's answer to the LOTR question.

[Why didn't Aragorn Let Theoden kill Grima?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35794/why-didnt-aragorn-let-theoden-kill-grima/35796#35796)

I found that he quoted  source material from the books very nicely to back his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Catija's answer to below mentioned question

[Why did they use Head & Shoulders to fight the alien invaders in Evolution?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33936/why-did-they-use-head-shoulders-to-fight-the-alien-invaders-in-evolution/33938#33938)

**Reason:** I was afraid to see lots of comment and answer like "for product placement, duh" but the first and only remaining answer was perfect to me and deserve appreciation.