# Rewards for the best answer from the 3rd quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2015-completed) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/49), I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from July 1st 2015 through September 30th 2015 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/375634)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

**Results**:-

[Top answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41505/subtitling-vs-dubbing-and-vice-versa/41514#41514) has been given bounty worth 200 points.
As a consolation, [second highest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/how-does-iron-mans-costume-serve-to-emphasize-the-aspects-of-his-character/41161#41161) scoring answer has also got 100 point bounty and [third highest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38584/woodrughs-way-of-holding-a-gun-is-taken-from-where/38653#38653) with a 50 point bounty. Keep answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is *not* considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of my favorite answers this quarter was a recently answered question posted by **Catija**.

This [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41514/1190) not only answered the question being asked, "**What are the benefits for viewers of subtitling over dubbing -or- dubbing over subtitling foreign TV and film?**" but also provided detailed information which enabled me to learn something new.

Answer (score 3):

I really like [my answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/how-does-iron-mans-costume-serve-to-emphasize-the-aspects-of-his-character/41161#41161) to ["How does Iron Man's costume serve to emphasize the aspects of his character?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/how-does-iron-mans-costume-serve-to-emphasize-the-aspects-of-his-character/), which takes a look at Tony Stark's character development over the course of several films in order to demonstrate how his armour is a reflection of the PTSD he feels after his time in Afghanistan in *Iron Man*.

Comment: As expected and MCU answer from u ;p anyways +1.

Comment: That also reminds me that, i never liked the downvote on that questions.

Answer (score 2):

I also liked [John Smith Optional's expert answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/38653/4386) about **gun positions in *True Detective***. What might seem like an actor's affectation was actually rooted in a real practice, and that was very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Chris' answer to :-

[Why is Dorne culturally so different from the rest of Westeros?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39355/1190)

**Reason:** Detailed answer representing good analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I like me some inside information. This is why one of my favorite answers from this quarter was [Chopper3's explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36557/4386) about **TV revenue**. I felt it deserved more recognition, it's quite informative!

Answer (score 0):

Catija's answer to the question

[Is there any information if Deadpool will break the fourth wall in the 2016 film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39054/1190)

**Reason:** Because i wanted to save that question from start but waited for community support which did came later. Catija's answer also responsible in question recovery too. Her edit was also good but that's not the point here to consider. So i think this answer deserve the extra point.