# Rewards for the best answer from the 4th quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2015) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2015?cb=1), I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from October 1st 2015 through December 31st 2015 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/419166/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

**Results**:-

[Top Voted Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44286/why-do-mickeys-ears-rotate-and-shift-location-when-he-is-not-facing-the-camera/44288#44288) of Walt's will be rewarded with bounty worth 200. For the first runner up there is a tie between three answer ([1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43215/who-will-say-start-camera-action-when-the-director-casts-himself-in-the-main-r/43217#43217),[2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42432/who-designed-the-batman-balloons/43581#43581),[3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43222/is-clapping-the-clapper-just-tradition-at-this-point/43235#43235)). Two answers are from Catija and one from Richard. Each will earn bounty worth 100.

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Walt's Answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44286/why-do-mickeys-ears-rotate-and-shift-location-when-he-is-not-facing-the-camera/44288#44288) to **Why do Mickey's ears rotate and shift location when he is not facing the camera**

The answer was well researched and provided various facts that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

[Catija](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420/catija)'s answer to

[Who will say “start camera action” when the director casts himself in the main role?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43217/1190)

**Reason:** Because she has given us good answer again. And deserve appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

**Richard**'s [research](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42432/who-designed-the-batman-balloons/43581#43581) on the *Batman* balloon designer, for its *detective work*. I appreciate good sleuthing and it's also a slightly underrated answer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

**Catija**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43222/is-clapping-the-clapper-just-tradition-at-this-point/43235#43235) about the need for clappers, for its *expertise*. Her answers are usually informative, knowledgeable and well-researched, and this one is no exception!

Answer (score 2):

[ghostdog](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22599/ghostdog)'s answer to :-

[What is the world's first movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42182/1190)

**Reason:** Because it was really good answer to one of the controversial question of this quarter.

Answer (score 1):

My nomination is for [Richard's answer on the most siblings in a film](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43615/26325).

I really enjoyed how it played with the rules of the question (as originally written), and gave a great answer. In short it made me laugh and was clearly the correct answer even though it was also not what the OP was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

[MattD](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/5733/mattd)'s answer to

[What exactly is 70mm print and why does anyone care?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45429/1190)

**Reason:** It should be clear from public response, it have double upvote then  accepted answer and I personally liked it too.

Answer (score 1):

**Andrew Thompson**'s [explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42203/why-does-t-1000-try-to-force-sarah-connor-to-call-her-son/42207#42207) for why the T-1000 tortures Sarah, for *solid reasoning*: Even though the question produced many possible answers, this answer's sound logic is the only thing that actually changed my mind about this scene.

Answer (score -2):

My favorite answer of this quarter is [Walt's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45573/29292) of **Office Space** to the post [Movie about the software programmers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45572/29292).

**Reason**: It helped me to identify the movie after long years. He provided the description for most of my key points.

After seeing the up-votes to the answer, I came to know that how many of them still loves [Office Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/combined) movie.

<sup>It was answered on Dec 30 '15 with 49 up-votes</sup>

Comment: Very kind of you and happy to help - but I must admit that my answer wasn't unlike many other ID answers... it's just happened to be about a beloved cult film, like you said. ;) [Looking forward to the entries in this post - I'll put up a few myself when I have the time.]

Comment: @Walt: tl;tr I was tried to re-call the movie name for a long years but didn't, I some what active in Stack Overflow and didn't aware of the MOVIES&TV community. One day just saw a question in the _Hot Network Questions_ about the _Identify-this-movie_ post. So just joined this community and posted the long waiting question then got good welcome, obviously the answer also.

Comment: @Walt Don't wait to long with that, though.