# Rewards for the best answer from the 1st quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2015) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-1st-quarter-of-2016), I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from January 1st 2016 through March 31st 2016 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 1st quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/467649/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

**Results**:-

[Top Voted Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49987/how-do-actors-avoid-looking-into-the-camera/49988#49988) of Catija's will be rewarded with bounty worth 200. For the [first runner up](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/character-deaths-in-the-walking-dead-show-vs-comic/51361#51361) will be awarded bounty of 100 reputation. For the second runner-ups([1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51065/what-traits-do-theater-actors-have/51067#51067), [2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50381/why-doesnt-the-mosasaurus-attack-the-audience-since-we-know-it-can-reach-them/50387#50387)), each will get bounty worth 50 reputation.

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Catija's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49988/1190)** answer to [How do actors avoid looking into the camera?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49987/27759)

I really like questions like this which address some general issue in the film-making world rather than just a plot point in a particular film, and this one is particularly relatable since it's a problem that almost any amateur actor will have experienced. Catija's answer was nice and thorough, covering many different facets of the issue and ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 6):

**[Wad Cheber](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51361/1190)**'s answer to [Character Death's in The Walking Dead show vs comic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/character-deaths-in-the-walking-dead-show-vs-comic)

I was really expecting a lot of negative responses or comments trying to get me to find an answer elsewhere. But this user really took a lot of time and effort and put in some great examples including screenshots and comic strip samples showing similar deaths and same deaths and honestly answered my question to a level that I never expected but truly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!  It was more a matter of time than effort, and I don't think it's a great answer, but I appreciate the gratitude.  Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

[**ghostdog's** answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51067/1190) to [What traits do theater actors have?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51065/what-traits-do-theater-actors-have) for a great amount of details regarding differences between theater and film acting.

Answer (score 3):

[Snowman's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50387/1190) to [Why doesn't the Mosasaurus attack the audience since we know it can reach them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50381/27264) . It includes details, a conclusion, and logical references to make the answer great.