# Rewards for the best answer from the 2nd quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-1st-quarter-of-2016) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2016), I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from April 1st 2016 through June 30th 2016 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/507919/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2016-04-01&Count=1617)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after completion of the event on 25th July 2016.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

**Results:-**

[Top Voted Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/does-mickey-mouse-not-have-a-last-name/55723#55723) of KutuluMike's will be rewarded with bounty worth 200. [First runner up](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52980/why-is-discovery-one-covered-in-sulphur-in-2010-the-year-we-make-contact/52981#52981) answer of Swan will be awarded bounty of 100 reputation. For the [second runner-up](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50806/why-was-there-light-emanating-from-batmans-suit/51388#51388) answer of cde will get bounty worth 50 reputation.

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**KutuluMike's**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/does-mickey-mouse-not-have-a-last-name/55723#55723) answer to the question [**Does Mickey Mouse not have a last name?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/does-mickey-mouse-not-have-a-last-name)

This answer also deserves recognition for providing detailed information.

Comment: Was about to nominate it.  So, a (+1) anyways :)

Answer (score 5):

[**Swan's**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52980/why-is-discovery-one-covered-in-sulphur-in-2010-the-year-we-make-contact/52981#52981) answer to [**Why is Discovery One covered in sulfur in "2010: The Year We Make Contact"?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52980/why-is-discovery-one-covered-in-sulphur-in-2010-the-year-we-make-contact)

This answer not only provided detailed information while answering the question, it also attracted several new users to the community.

Answer (score 4):

[cde's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51388/1190) answer to [Why was there light emanating from Batman's suit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50806/why-was-there-light-emanating-from-batmans-suit)

Because that answer got less appreciation then it deserve. It's a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

[user568458's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/55890/1190) answer to [Why do sieges work in Westeros?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/why-do-sieges-work-in-westeros)

Answer presented with in universe and out of universe explanation both and deserve more appreciation.