# Rewards for the best answer from the 3rd quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2016) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2438/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2016), I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from July 1st 2016 through September 30th 2016 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/553860/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2016-07-01&Count=1300)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 24th October 2016.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

**Results:-**

[Top Voted Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56879/1190) of Swan's will be rewarded with bounty worth 300. [First runner up](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11072/why-does-no-one-notice-the-jokers-presence-as-a-policeman-during-the-mayors-sp/59154#59154) answer of steelerfan will be awarded bounty of 200 reputation. For the second runner-up answer of [A J](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/whats-the-meaning-of-abbreviations-in-credits-asc-pga/60258#60258) and  [KutuluMike](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60581/how-do-actors-make-eye-contact-with-cgi-characters/60582#60582) will get bounty worth 100 reputation each.

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Swan's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-this-dog-really-biting-in-the-thing/56879#56879) to the question [What is this dog really biting in The Thing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-this-dog-really-biting-in-the-thing)

**Swan took the initiative to contact John Carpenter (director) and Stuart Cohen(producer) to get an answer to this question.  This answer deserved more attention and recognition.**

Answer (score 7):

steelerfan's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/59154/1190) to [Why does no one notice the Joker's presence as a policeman during the mayor's speech?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11072/why-does-no-one-notice-the-jokers-presence-as-a-policeman-during-the-mayors-sp)

That question was closed on vague grounds and after reopening it got quite appreciable answer from steelerfan which seems worth giving bounty too.

Answer (score 6):

I'd nominate [KutulMike](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1146/kutulumike)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60582/27264) to the question [How do actors make eye contact with CGI characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60581/27264).

It is great answer and deserves an additional reward.

Answer (score 5):

A J's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60258/27264) to the question [What's the meaning of abbreviations in credits? (ASC, PGA, …)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60257/27264).

This answer provides most of the abbreviations used by people involved in movie making. It lists all popular ones in one answer, and gives more details other than just their meaning.

Answer (score 4):

**Paulie_D's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60466/how-did-mongo-punch-the-horse/60468#60468) to the question [How did Mongo punch the horse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60466/how-did-mongo-punch-the-horse)

This answer was well researched and provided additional insight into the particular film technique that was asked about.

Answer (score 3):

dbugger's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60314/1190) on [Is Toy Story inspired by The Velveteen Rabbit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44351/is-toy-story-inspired-by-the-velveteen-rabbit)

Well researched answer which didn't got much appreciation that it deserve.

Comment: As they say at the Oscars, "it's an honor just to be nominated."

Answer (score 3):

[**Swan's** answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/57219/19042) to [Mellish getting emotional over Hitler Youth knife](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/29822/mellish-getting-emotional-over-hitler-youth-knife)

I think the level of detail in this answer would match the standards of History SE. It's much better than the accepted one and should have received far more appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

cde's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60119/1190) on my own question [What was Bruce Wayne's obsession with unusual looking statues?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60101/what-was-bruce-waynes-obsession-with-unusual-looking-statues)

This is in an example of a case where non top voted answer surpass in quality to the top voted answer and might need more appreciation.