# Rewards for the best answer from the 4th quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

First I want to wish you all **Happy New Year**. And in continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2016) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016), I'd ask the community again for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from October 1st 2016 through December 31st 2016 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/610494/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2016-10-01&Count=1500)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 23rd January 2017.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

## Results:-

**Winner - [Walt](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/meaning-of-the-silence-of-the-lambs-poster/61823#61823)

1st Runner-up - [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60021/where-did-the-line-about-the-reason-for-the-big-eyes-come-from/65819#65819)

2nd Runner-up - [dbugger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65922/did-rowan-atkinsons-character-purposely-distract-the-check-in-agent/65939#65939), [Dr R Dizzle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62407/does-the-iron-man-movie-ever-establish-a-convincing-motive-for-the-main-villain/62409#62409) and [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65382/1190)**

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would like to nominate [Walt's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386/walt) [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/meaning-of-the-silence-of-the-lambs-poster/61823#61823) to  [*Meaning of the Silence of the Lambs poster*.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/meaning-of-the-silence-of-the-lambs-poster)

The answer was well researched and provided well sourced information which is always important in providing an answer.

Answer (score 11):

[steelersquirrel's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65819/19042) to [Where did the line about the reason for the big eyes come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60021/where-did-the-line-about-the-reason-for-the-big-eyes-come-from). She took the effort to contact the writer Larry Karaszewski. It is also a winner of the December challenge of solving the unanswered questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nomination!  That is greatly appreciated and I am extremely flattered :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to nominate Steelersquirrel's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65382/27264) to [Why is Titanic's Astor asking if Jack is from the Boston Dawsons?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65379/27264). This answer is quite good and well-researched.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [dbugger's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/37467/dbugger) [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65922/did-rowan-atkinsons-character-purposely-distract-the-check-in-agent/65939#65939) to [*Did Rowan Atkinson's character purposely distract the check in agent?*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65922/did-rowan-atkinsons-character-purposely-distract-the-check-in-agent)

This answer provided well sourced information along with revealing unknown facts to the OP as well as myself.

Comment: Great question and answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [Dr R Dizzle's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/62409/1190) to [Does the Iron Man movie ever establish a convincing motive for the main villain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62407/does-the-iron-man-movie-ever-establish-a-convincing-motive-for-the-main-villain)

It's quite detailed and the magazine cover were cherry on the cake.

Answer (score 5):

I am nominating the [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63665/what-are-all-the-magical-creatures-beasts-in-newt-scamanders-suitcase/63668#63668) given by [Ghoti and Chips](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42655/ghoti-and-chips) on the question [*What are all the magical creatures/beasts in Newt Scamander's suitcase?*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63665/what-are-all-the-magical-creatures-beasts-in-newt-scamanders-suitcase)

The answer was well formatted and provided a list of each creature as well as visuals and well sourced information about each creature.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate [Paulie_D's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/64955/1190) to my own question [How did Preacher get away with an exploding Tom Cruise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/how-did-preacher-get-away-with-an-exploding-tom-cruise)

Well sourced answer which might deserve more attention.

Answer (score 5):

I'm nominating [Dannie's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/61975/4386) to [What is the first movie to show this hard work message at the very end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61974/what-is-the-first-movie-to-show-this-hard-work-message-at-the-very-end) which taught me an interesting fact about a relatively new aspect of film credits.

Answer (score 3):

I'll nominate [**Shiz Z's  answer'**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/64905/34317) to *Why did some people feel Lonely Are the Brave was “brutal” and “sadistic”?*

I had my initial issues with the *question* but the answer was well researched and balanced.

It also won the Kirk Douglas Topic Challenge

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to nominate AJ's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65360/27264) to [Was Carrie Fisher's voice used in Rogue One?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65341/27264). It is well-researched, but didn't get much attention.

Answer (score 3):

I am nominating [Steve-O](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43124/steve-o)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63369/52) to the question [Ending of babadook](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27494/ending-of-babadook/63369#63369)

The answer takes a different approach to answering the question and frankly deserves more love.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Anu7' answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63596/1190) to  [Why didn't Harry Potter become an Obscurial?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/why-didnt-harry-potter-become-an-obscurial).

It's quite detailed and gave question a good closer.