# Rewards for the best answer from the 1st quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016), I'd ask the community again for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from January 1st 2017 through March 31st 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 1st quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/653300/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2017-01-01&Count=1600)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 24th April 2017.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

## Results:-

**Winner - [Cearon O'Flynn](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68360/1190), [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67829/1190)

1st Runner-up - [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67756/1190)

2nd Runner-up - [A J](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68998/1190)**

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 11):

I would like to nominate [Cearon O'Flynn's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68360/1190) to [Is Agrabah in India?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68044/is-agrabah-in-india)

This answer shows how patience can help making a great answer, even considering every little update of question and countering it with great details.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to nominate [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67829/27264) to [What is the significance of Kat's despising of Hemingway?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67821/27264)

This answer has provided nice analysis of dialogues and character.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate **Paulie_D's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67749/were-oranges-an-intentional-use-of-symbolism-by-filmmakers/67756#67756) to [Were oranges an intentional use of symbolism by filmmakers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67749/were-oranges-an-intentional-use-of-symbolism-by-filmmakers)

Paulie_D provided DVD commentary from filmmakers to answer the question along with another reliable source.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate my [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68998/27264) to [Why is the biography of comedian Andy Kaufman titled “Man on the Moon”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68996/27264)

This answer provides well-researched analysis of title with sources.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate **Walt's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/why-did-groundhog-day-take-place-on-groundhog-day/68049#68049) to [Why did Groundhog day take place on Groundhog day?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/why-did-groundhog-day-take-place-on-groundhog-day)

Walt found a great source which fully answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate **BlueMoon93's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69428/what-does-the-title-gone-in-60-seconds-mean/69430#69430) to [What does the title "Gone in 60 Seconds" mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69428/what-does-the-title-gone-in-60-seconds-mean)

BlueMoon93 provided a great reference along with finding the original movie poster which helped answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate **Paulie_D's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/did-napoleon-wilson-reappear-as-snake-plissken/70297#70297) to [Did Napoleon Wilson "reappear" as Snake Plissken?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/did-napoleon-wilson-reappear-as-snake-plissken)

Paulie_D found a great source from the filmmaker.  This answer did not get the recognition that it deserved.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67543/27264) to [How did Alfred's story about the bandit help Bruce in dealing with the Joker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67539/27264)

This answer has provided nice analysis about the plot-point.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68057/27264) to [Why were people led to believe that the Apollo mission was fake in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64087/27264)

This answer has provided nice analysis about the movie element along with the interview of screenwriters, Christopher and Jonathan Nolan.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate **AJ's** [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68667/why-was-there-a-line-in-fifty-shades-darker-from-the-movie-working-girl/68668#68668) to [Why was there a line in "Fifty Shades Darker" from the movie "Working Girl"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68667/why-was-there-a-line-in-fifty-shades-darker-from-the-movie-working-girl)

AJ provided a detailed answer to the question while citing 2 separate sources.  This answer also did not receive the attention that it deserved.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to nominate [Paulie_D's answer](http://(https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67294/1190)) to my own question [What was the significance of Red Indian and the Mascot's apperances?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/what-was-the-siginifcance-of-red-indian-and-the-mascots-apperances).

Nice elaborated answer with support from the show itself and this is the type of answer which shows the effective use of images/screenshots.

Comment: @Paulie_D DV is on all the posts so it doesn't even make any sense :D

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah...it's a little weird.  Don't worry, here have a +1 :)