# Favourite questions and answers from the 3rd quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1847/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from July 1st 2015 through September 30th 2015.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2015-07..2015-09) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2015-07..2015-09). Since we currently get ~1.1k/1.6k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 3rd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/369983)
- [Questions with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/369984)
- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/369986)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

If you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1956/49)**.

Answer (score 4):

I only have time to do this gradually, so I'll go over them one month at a time (<s>and put up some of these on the rewards thread later on</s> I'll never make it. I settled for putting up 1 from July and 1 from August). But fear not, I'll just give out bounties myself to 5 of them. :)

**July 2015**

- [ComicSansMS's informative answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36414/4386) about the inspiration for Cronenberg's *Naked Lunch*
- [Napoleon's thorough analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36466/4386) of Tesla's role in *The Prestige*
- [Chopper3's knowledgeable (and slightly underrated) explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36557/4386) of how TV revenue works
- All the answers for [this decanter question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/whiskey-in-us-movies-out-of-plain-glass-decanters-a-movie-or-culture-thing), that prove one thing about us: *We know our booze!*

**August 2015**

- [John Smith Optional's expert answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/38653/4386) about a certain gun position in *True Detective*
- [Catija's careful analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/38803/4386) of the Hitchcock homage in *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*
- [George Adam's fun question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39394/why-do-people-repeatedly-hit-the-phone-hook-switch-when-disconnected) about a common phone cliche and some illuminating answers
- I'm not sure there's a definitive answer to [Chris Noe's question about the opposite of a MacGuffin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39524/what-would-be-the-opposite-of-a-macguffin), but it sure led to a fascinating debate

**September 2015**

- The interesting [Subbing vs. Dubbing debate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41505/subtitling-vs-dubbing-and-vice-versa), notable not only for Catija's great answer (that was justly rewarded) but also for the many perspectives on the issue from different cultures
- [Meat Trademark's good answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41343/4386) to a question about the rickety bridge scene in *Sorcerer*
- *Breaking Bad* ended 2 years ago, but it keeps providing us with good material. My favorite was [Pesetas74's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40884/was-walter-going-to-kill-jesse) for a finale question I always wondered about; it actually changed my mind about this particular scene. Other highlights include the insights into Walt and Jesse's relationship [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/why-is-walt-obsessed-with-jesse) and the answers to [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/positive-outcomes-of-walters-actions) and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39652/is-it-really-possible-to-produce-99-9-crystal-meth) (in an entirely **Don't**-DIY way, of course!)
- ***Honorable mentions:*** [These](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40789/what-happened-to-robert-englund) very nice (and slightly unsung) Q&A about Robert Englund's role in *New Nightmare*, and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41481/questions-about-skiing-scene-in-on-her-majestys-secret-service) *highly* informed and exhaustive answer about the ski scene in *OHMSS*

Comment: *Disclaimer:* Still avoiding GoT spoilers, so I haven't read most of the questions about it. But damn, [this thread](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38712/what-is-the-inspiration-for-trial-by-combat) certainly *looks* impressive... (Oh, and [this Walking Dead one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39067/how-are-michonnes-zombies-made) is pretty good too)

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed writing [my answer to "Why did Tony Stark design the Hulkbuster armor?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41124/8686), in which I take a small look at Bruce Banner's relationship with his alter-ego, The Hulk, in order to explain why he would have helped Tony Stark create the Hulkbuster suit.

I also enjoyed reading [@cde's answer to "How did Veronica get from Earth's orbit to Wakanda in a matter of seconds?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39239/how-did-veronica-get-from-earths-orbit-to-wakanda-in-a-matter-of-seconds/39243#39243), which uses real life maths and physics and a knowledge of space-y stuff in order to prove that the Hulkbuster suit could have reached Tony within a few minutes.

Comment: You're really an MCU guy, eh? But well, nice answers indeed. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It's my jam.