# Favourite questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

The last year is over and as done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from October 1st 2015 through December 31th 2015.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2015-10..2015-12) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2015-10..2015-12). Since we currently get ~1.2k/1.6k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 4th quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/419164)
- [Questions with most votes from 4th quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/419165)
- [Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/419166)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2075/49)**.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to highlight [Richard's answer on the most siblings in a film](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43615/26325).

I really enjoyed how it played with the rules of the question (as originally written), and gave a great answer. In short it made me laugh and was clearly the correct answer even though it was also not what the OP was expecting.

Answer (score 5):

**QUESTION**

[**Why did Sylvester Stallone empty and reload his gun?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44617/why-did-sylvester-stallone-empty-and-reload-his-gun) asked by **sanpaco**

This was a valid question and an interesting observation about this particular movie that I never would have realized had the question not been asked.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of my favorites (in addition to my selections [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2015)):

- Catija's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43637/filming-timespan-of-jeopardy/43668#43668) about the inner workings of Jeopardy that got a well-deserved bounty;
- [This](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43448/why-do-old-movies-sound-like-old-movies/) fascinating [though deceptively-titled ;)] question, and [the equally fascinating top answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43448/why-do-old-movies-sound-like-old-movies/43458#43458), about old movie 'sound'. (Sadly, they're both from deleted accounts.)

Comment: Don't hesitate to also mention some stuff you already mentioned in the other thread. Noone said this is supposed to be an either-or situation.

Comment: Right, sorry. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Answers

I quite liked my own answer to this. All the scripts and novelisations in the world aren't gonna answer some questions. Sometimes you've just got to go look at the thing:

- **[How can a plant grow in a refrigerator?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43313/how-can-a-plant-grow-in-a-refrigerator)**

And this one was a fun one to answer. It involved watching many, many (many) car crash videos.

- **[How many KITTs were destroyed during production of the '80s Knight Rider series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44268/how-many-kitts-were-destroyed-during-production-of-the-80s-knight-rider-series)**

### Questions

I like this question. It's a real thinker and although there's a canonical answer (from the novel), I actually liked the accepted answer better as well

- **[In Back to the Future, how did Marty get the timing right with the lightning strike?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42848/in-back-to-the-future-how-did-marty-get-the-timing-right-with-the-lightning-str)**

It seemed like everyone had an opinion on this one

- **[Is it necessary to watch Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith before embarking on Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44907/is-it-necessary-to-watch-star-wars-episode-iii-revenge-of-the-sith-before-emb)**

Answer (score 1):

**Question**

- **[What is Jack Nicholson tossing aside in this scene in The Shining?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43645/what-is-jack-nicholson-tossing-aside-in-this-scene-in-the-shining)**

I thought this question was great, simple yet very specific and with a great visual aid allowing people to respond without having to go rewatch the whole movie to find the 4 second scene the question is asking about.

**Answers**

- **[What are we to make of the ending of The Great Silence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26830/what-are-we-to-make-of-the-ending-of-the-great-silence/44788#44788)**

I would nominate this question if it was asked in the time period so instead I'll nominate my answer for it which I also really enjoyed researching and writing.

I really enjoyed the fact that this question led me to a great movie that I'd never seen before, and then it led me to research the film and find some very interesting analysis of the plot and the director's motives in making the movie the way he did.  I think there are often questions and answers like this that don't get as much attention due to the fact that they are obscure movies, but I look at these as opportunities to find new things to watch. It was a very satisfying experience.

- **[What is Jack Nicholson tossing aside in this scene in The Shining?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43654/49)**

Yes nominating this for answer as well. The accepted answer was very thorough and taught me more than I'll ever need to know about plate rings. Kudos to the answerer for putting that much time into a quality answer.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this for your great words in the middle section, not only because it was my question but because you make great points about the site encouraging to watch films and contributing to their appreciation. But I can't, because of that utterly useless and irrelevant *Shining* question that got it into HNQ for no valid reason. But to each his own. Still thank you for your insights.

Comment: Haha, you have a point that the question is relatively useless but I think what I liked about it was how it represented how this site can take something as stupid as "what are those things" and people will put together a high quality answer. IE I liked the effort put into the asking and answering of such a question and I think if all users used this as a standard of thoroughness we'd all be better off. Anyway, like you say, to each his own :)

Answer (score 0):

Not to toot my own horn (OK, I'll toot it...), but the answer to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44467/trading-places-how-long-was-valentine-working-for-the-dukes/44475#44475) was legendary.  **:oD**