# Favourite questions and answers from the 1st quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

The new year has begun and as done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2071/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from January 1st 2016 through March 31th 2016.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016-01..2016-03) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2016-01..2016-03). Since we currently get ~1.2k/1.8k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 1st quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/467647)
- [Questions with most votes from 1st quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/467648)
- [Answers with most votes from 1st quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/467649)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2214/49)**.

Comment: Is there a way to see the 1st quarter bountries earned?

Comment: @Decypher Probably only with an appropriate SEDE query.

Answer (score 5):

**ANSWER**

**Walt's** answer to the question: [Why Did the Dude hate the Eagles so much?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46682/22792) was my favorite answer due to the question being answered fully coupled with excellent research and sources.

Answer (score 3):

1. [What traits do theater actors have?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51065/what-traits-do-theater-actors-have)

is something that always interested me, so I'm really glad that this question has been asked. Sadly it seems that it didn't receive much attention.

2. [The most actors playing the same role in one movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49533/the-most-actors-playing-the-same-role-in-one-movie)

while I'm not a fan of [the question about multiple roles played by the same actor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49204/511) I liked this one as a really large number of actors playing a single role is a very rare case in a movie.

3. [What are the triangles around Kermit's neck?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49390/what-are-the-triangles-around-kermits-neck)

I was surprised that I've never found the 'triangles' to be unusual, while obviously it's not something that frogs have and I was even more surprised by the answer.

4. [What do the owls have to do with the events of Twin Peaks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50266/what-do-the-owls-have-to-do-with-the-events-of-twin-peaks)

I think everyone who watched *Twin Peaks* remembers the owls. I really hope for a good (any?) answer to this question.

Number 3 has a really good answer from **cde** and in my opinion **ghostdog's** answer to number 1 is exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

1. The question [Why doesn't Deadpool's healing ability heal his skin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49176/27264)
2. Snowman's answer to the question : [Why doesn't the Mosasaurus attack the audience since we know it can reach them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50381/27264). It includes logical references and details.
3. Andrew Martin's answer to the question : [Who is the Bond Girl in Skyfall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49488/27264). It is coupled with research, resources and good explanation.
4. Richard's answer to the question : [What happened to other characters from previous movies of Jurassic Park in Jurassic World](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51951/27264)