# Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2211/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from April 1st 2016 through June 30th 2016.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016-04..2016-06) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2016-04..2016-06). Since we currently get ~1.1k/1.6k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 2nd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/507155)
- [Questions with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/507156)
- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/507157)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2016)**

Answer (score 4):

I am a very new user here, but already loving the site. So, here are my favourites from the three categories:

1. [Why are porn films called blue films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56212/25800):  I knew that porn films are called blue films, but didn't really know the reason behind it. So, this question is what I always had subconsciously.
2. [Can a single bullet from a handgun kill three people in the way Deadpool did?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55640/25800): This was my own question. I was really surprised by the scene, which was an awesomely shot fight scene in DeadPool
3. [Kutulu Mike's answer to Does Mickey Mouse not have a last name?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/does-mickey-mouse-not-have-a-last-name/55723#55723): Now, who doesn't want to know whether Mickey has a last name or not :)

Answer (score 1):

1. [First example of “ringing in ears” sound design?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51301/first-example-of-ringing-in-ears-sound-design)
2. [Where does the "TV-Look" vs "Cinematic-Look" come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55311/where-does-the-tv-look-vs-cinematic-look-come-from)

These two are simply very interesting questions with good answers.

3. **The accepted answer to** [How does Andy Dufresne reattach the poster to the wall in Shawshank Redemption?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/how-does-andy-dufresne-reattach-the-poster-to-the-wall-in-shawshank-redemption)

We don't often see answers based on experimentation on this SE, so I think it deserves appreciation.