# Favourite questions and answers from the 3rd quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2334/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from July 1st 2016 through September 30th 2016.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016-07..2016-09) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2016-07..2016-09). Since we currently get ~1.1k/1.6k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 3rd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/551092)
- [Questions with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/551093)
- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/551094)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/49)**

Answer (score 8):

**Swan's** [Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-this-dog-really-biting-in-the-thing/56879#56879) to the question **"What is the dog really biting in The Thing?"**

Swan actually took the initiative to contact John Carpenter (the director) and Stuart Cohen (the producer) to answer this question.  This answer deserves far more recognition and appreciation.

**Paulie_D's** [Answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60466/how-did-mongo-punch-the-horse/60468#60468) to the question **"How did Mongo punch the horse?"**

This answer was well researched and provided additional insight into the particular film technique that was asked about.

Answer (score 8):

**A J's** [Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61134/term-for-movies-taking-place-during-the-main-events-of-its-predecessor) **"Term for movies taking place during the main events of its predecessor?"**

This was an interesting question that did not get the recognition that it deserved.

**Pale Blue Dot's** [Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61131/did-the-creators-of-seinfeld-ever-have-an-alternate-ending-in-their-mind-for-the) **"Did the creators of Seinfeld ever have an alternate ending in their mind for the show?"**

This was an interesting question that did not get the recognition that it deserved.

Comment: You could actually put all your different answers into one for conciseness. It can get a little confusing with so many different small answers. I hope you all don't mistake this question for the one asking for rewards the best answer. You can very well list more than one question and answer in your answers here, as well as provide more elaborations about them.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That's fine, but, what if someone doesn't agree with all of the ones listed?  What if someone only likes one of the suggestions but not the other ones?  They're all in one post, so you would have to upvote or downvote all of them wouldn't you?

Comment: Sure, I guess it's fine. I was just making sure.

Answer (score 3):

[Is Game of Thrones the first book adaptation which has overtaken the book it's adapting?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59824/is-game-of-thrones-the-first-book-adaptation-which-has-overtaken-the-book-its-a)

GoT story progressed over the last novel, while there are still novels to be published, which is a very unusual situation. Even before this question was asked I was really interested if this is a first time such situation occurred and if not, what was the first occurrence.

[Does the sun rise from the West in Middle Earth?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/does-the-sun-rise-from-the-west-in-middle-earth)

OP was very perceptive to notice this interesting discrepancy. The question also has a very good [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56690/19042) from Todd Wilcox.

[**Swan's** answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/57219/19042) to [Mellish getting emotional over Hitler Youth knife](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/29822/mellish-getting-emotional-over-hitler-youth-knife)

Very good and extremely detailed answer (much better than the accepted one) that should have received far more appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

**Walt's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60506/27264) to the [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60049/27264) "Comedy movie/TV show featuring a lactating girl convincing a boy to consume her breast milk".**

That was very hard to find, and Walt's answer didn't get much appreciation it should have received.

Comment: I hope you all don't mistake this question for the one asking for rewards the best answer. You can very well list more than one question and answer in your answers here, as well as provide more elaborations about them.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I didn't.