# Favourite questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2438/49), we'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from October 1st 2016 through December 31th 2016.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016-10..2016-12) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2016-10..2016-12). Since we currently get ~1.1k/1.6k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 4th quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/612812)
- [Questions with most votes from 4th quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/612813)
- [Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/612814)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. There's also no requirement to only mention one post per meta answer, since this is **not a contest** of any kind. Just list as many and whatever posts you want. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558/49)**

Answer (score 9):

I liked BrettFromLA's question...

[**Why are the railings in Rivendell so low?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/why-are-the-railings-in-rivendell-so-low)

Such a simple question for something that stared us in the face...but only Brett asked!

---

I'll also throw in SteelerSquirrel's

[**Does Mia mistake Vincent's heroin for cocaine because it's in a baggie rather than a balloon?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64162/does-mia-mistake-vincents-heroin-for-cocaine-because-its-in-a-baggie-rather-th)

Together with JohnnyBones's [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/64172/34317) to the same...it makes a pow(d)erful combo.

---

I'm quite proud of my own [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/how-did-preacher-get-away-with-an-exploding-tom-cruise/64955#64955) to **How did *Preacher* get away with an exploding Tom Cruise?**

I had to do a fair bit of googling for that one....turned out nice.

Answer (score 6):

**QUESTIONS:**

**DVK's** question [**Was O-Ren Ishii's sword made by Hattori Hanzo?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65647/was-o-ren-ishiis-sword-made-by-hattori-hanzo)

This was a very interesting question that did not get the recognition that it deserved.

---

**Mikey's** question [**What mitigation is taken while filming raining scenes?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64768/what-mitigation-is-taken-while-filming-raining-scenes)

This was a great question that attracted well researched answers.

---

**Alvaro Montoro's** question [**Why does the wicked witch have no power here?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64201/why-does-the-wicked-witch-have-no-power-here)

This was another terrific question that did not get the recognition and attention that it deserved.

---

**Thunderforge's** question [**Why is the trailer for Highlander: Endgame so radically different from the final film?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63753/why-is-the-trailer-for-highlander-endgame-so-radically-different-from-the-final)

After researching this question for the bounty reward, I discovered that this was indeed a controversy for fans and it made for a terrific question to ask.