# Is a "casting" question about a movie-in-the making on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on a screenplay that I hope/dream will be made into a movie. I've decided to "cast" Julia Roberts as a tough "Erin Brockovich" type boss. She has a 30-year old subordinate, "Phil Potter" by name, whose shoes are well filled by Jonah Hill.

The plot later features "Phil Potter" 20 years later (aged 50) showing what he has learned from his old boss. My question is which contemporary actor might plausibly play a 50-year old version of Jonah Hill. May I ask it on this site?

Comment: Hmm, tough question (the meta one, not the actual one, well, both of them). I'm not sure if that really works, it might very likely come out totally opinion-based. But maybe it *could* work. I'm not 100% sure but my gut feeling says that's bound to be *"primarily opinion-based"*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I'll just have to be very specific about how and why I want the actor to be an older version of Jonah Hill. Based on what you've said, the question isn't necessarily off topic, just a hard sell.

Comment: Honestly, this is more of a production question.  I think it would work better if you generalized the question to ask the heart of the question: "What methods are used to show characters at different ages?"

Comment: @TomAu If your actual question is *Who do you recommend to play an older version of Jonah Hill?*, that's completely off topic as being an opinion based question with no real answer... not to mention the fact that precasting a film before even selling it to anyone is ... to put it nicely... completely unprofessional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we want practical questions about movie production?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/do-we-want-practical-questions-about-movie-production)

Comment: @Catija: OK, my bad. I didn't realize that this site was for "serious" movie people. I was thinking in terms of a "hobbyist," brainstorming etc. Visualizing who would play my parts in order to help me write the screenplay.

Comment: @TomAu It's not about us being **serious** movie people... We are **by definition** ***NOT*** a discussion site where chatting is encouraged. We are here to answer questions with *actual* answers.  That's why I think my suggested rephrasing is the best option for you.  It completely removes the issue of this being about production and makes it about the choices films take to portray people at different points in their life... which is both answerable and able to be exampled, as I've already done in my answer to your question.

Comment: @Catija: I have reworded the question to the best of my ability to adopt your suggested changes, and  have also used "Julia Roberts" and "Jonah Hill" as people "like" my characters (that is as examples, rather than as proposed "cast" members).

Comment: I've rolled this back, because to be fair on the person that attempted to answer it, you've changed it to a different question after someone had answered it.  If you'd like to ask the alternative question, I suggest you do so separately so it makes sense.

Comment: For what it is worth, I think your second question would probably be closed as 'primarily opinion based'.  As others have suggested, while we're not 'for serious movie people' - this is also not a discussion forum.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Thanks for your help. It seems like Catija and I have settled on a mutually acceptable compromise on the original question.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Asking questions asking for recommendations for anything is against the **Every answer is equally valid** rule on the [**Don't Ask Page**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Comment: I have retracted that version of the question. Thanks for your help in making what remained "answerable."