# Is it on-topic to ask for advice on filmmaking?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

A question asking, “[How would you credit people who gave writing suggestions but did not actually participate in writing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121211/1006)” was recently [left open in the close votes review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/close/95483) and currently remains open.

The OP of the question is involved in making a short film and is asking for advice on how to credit people who helped in the writing process. However, based on the community consensus in the 2014 meta discussion post, “[Do we want practical questions about movie production?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1234/1006)”, such questions about making a new work are off-topic. This is supported by all of the positively scored answers in that meta discussion:

> no: it is not fair game to ask for advice about making a new work

> Personally I don't think that this is a site catering to people making movies. This is for enthusiasts for finished movie and TV works.

Despite this, the [review queue log shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/close/95483) that at least three users are of the opinion that the question should be left open. This is *after* I had already linked to that [relevant meta discussion post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1234/1006) in my comment explaining why I think it should've been closed. It seems that some users think that the question is either not covered by the prior meta post I cited or that it is on-topic for some reason.

*I created this post to discuss and clarify the on-topicness of the question and questions of the same ilk, and to clarify if they fall under the scope of that meta discussion post.* I also want to point out that *the prior meta post is almost a decade old* (9 years and 6 months old currently), so maybe the community has changed its opinion on this topic.

Does the aforementioned [meta discussion post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1234/1006) cover this type of question or not? **Should we allow questions like this that seek advice on filmmaking?**

Comment: Is there anything that you think the existing meta discussions on this topic are missing? Or ist this *actually* a discussion about why that specific question was left open by a select few reviewers rather than the general scope discussion you're dressing it up as? In any case, according to our existing rules, that question can't really be left open in its current wording. If people want it to remain open, there needs to be some work put into rephrasing it. As it stands, the straight answer to your question is "no, we shouldn't, the existing consensus and practice are very clear about that".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It’s a bit of both. Apparently, at least three users with enough rep to vote on closing or reopening the question seem to think it’s on-topic and/or not covered by the meta post I cited. I made this post to discuss and clarify the question’s on-topicness, including if it's covered by that meta post.

Comment: Dupe of [Do we want practical questions about movie production?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/do-we-want-practical-questions-about-movie-production)

Comment: @galacticninja Reviewers disagree occasionally, sometimes they interpret stuff differently, sometimes they get things straight up wrong, sometimes the rules are a bit unclear and sometimes they just like/hate questions. Not every disagreeing review stems from a fundamental disagreement of swathes of the community with the core principles of this site. But we'll see. I'd agree with Valorum, though, that as a very broad scope question, this kind of is tackled by the existing discussion already. Maybe you can factor that in a bit more and ask in which way that question is not covered by it?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I have added more reasons to my meta post to clarify why the other meta post may not cover the question I'm referring to (and similar ones).

Comment: I disagreed with the closure for the reason I gave there: I believe that while the question was packaged as regarding (a new) production, the question seemed to be along the lines of asking how this problem is generally solved; how these writing credits are usually given. I hinted at the OP to edit their Q to redirect it in that way (along the lines of Catija's answer in the suggested duplicate).

Comment: @Joachim Your comment seems like a valid answer to me. Why don’t you post it as such, so that the community can weigh in on whether this is the best way to handle questions like this in the future?

Comment: I am puzzled why my question and answer here were both contradictorily downvoted without any explanation. It seems that some people do not share my perspective, but they have not offered any alternatives or counterarguments to what I posted. I wonder how the community wants to handle filmmaking advice questions in the future—close or leave open?

Comment: If the downvotes on this question are because you think this meta post is a duplicate of the other one, then that means you agree with the other one, which is saying to close filmmaking advice questions. But then my answer, which agrees with that other meta post, is also downvoted, which contradictorily means that the downvoters want to leave filmmaking advice questions open. So, which is it? Close or leave open?

Comment: I didn't answer because I voted to close. Not because I disagree with your intent, but because, as commented, I think the answers on the other question can be interpreted the way I interpreted them. But maybe you're right in that not being an emphatically helpful way to deal with the problem at hand. Besides, it's better to have more clear-cut answers.

Answer (score -1):

Questions about filmmaking that involve films that are still in production or not yet finished should be off-topic, since this site is for movie and TV enthusiasts, not filmmakers. However, if you are asking about finished work, it should be fine.

For example, this example question would be more on-topic because it is about a finished movie (based on “[How would you credit people who gave writing suggestions but did not actually participate in writing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121211/1006)”):

> Why did [a finished movie] use that particular credit format for [certain people]? According to various sources, these people gave valuable insights that helped shape, correct, and guide the plot. Some of their ideas were even used almost word for word in the final script. Why did they receive those credits?

Comment: *"Why did they get these credits?"* = Fine. *"What sort of credits should I give them?"* = Not fine.

Comment: @Valorum My sentiments exactly.

Comment: And where should filmmakers ask their questions?

Comment: @EtackSxchange There's no filmmaking SE. Some aspects of filmmaking may be on-topic at [video.se].

Comment: I started writing up an answer based on [that comment](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4959/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-for-advice-on-filmmaking?noredirect=1#comment14650_4959), but the more I write, the more I realize the problem was not that I disagree with you, but that a proper edit would have made that question on-topic—in fact, that it was rightfully closed, but could be reopened if the OP were to edit it to ask how such credits are usually given *in existing productions*.